# No value in vector when trying to display

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having some troubles with my current project. I have class of Jobs, which are saved inside `vector`. When I try to `push_back` or `pop_back` job my program works well (I can delete only as many times, as many times I add job).
But when I try to display what is inside my `vector` I get message: Nothing to display, `vector` is empty, altought I `push_back` some jobs.

```
void Job::generirateActivities(vector<Job> job_list) {

  Smt s1("Default1", 1, 2, 3);
  Smt s2("Default2", 2, 3, 4);

  Date d1(1, 1, 2001);
  Date d2(2, 2, 2002);

  Job j1(&s1, &d1);
  Job j2(&s2, &d2);

  job_list.push_back(a1);
  job_list.push_back(a2); 
}
```

And for printing I'm using:

```
void Job::printJobs(vector<Job> job_list) {
  if (job_list.empty())
    cout << "Nothing to display, vector is empty." << endl;
  else {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < job_list.size(); i++)
      cout << i + 1 << ". " <<job_list[i].toString() << endl;
  }
```

What could be wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `generirateActivities(vector<Job> job_list) {` - you *copy* the original vector, then append to the copy, not the original. Use a reference: `vector<job> &job_list`. Same for printing (though make it `const`).

Comment: Well, if I add & my project.exe stopped working...

Comment: @BoBTFish Why not post as answer?

Comment: @HC1122 Then you have another bug in your code, because BoBTFish is correct.

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve], it seems you have problems in code you haven't shown. (Note I am **not** asking you to just dump in your code, but to trim it to a useful working example of the problem).

Comment: @BoBTFish Ouch, that could be a problem, because its a lot of Classes and subclasses, and actually everything in code is important to come to this point where I am now.

Comment: Is "a1" and "a2" supposed to be "j1" and "j2"? Storing pointers to local variables is usually a terrible idea.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, ofcourse, my bad when editing and translating code from my native language.

Comment: @HC1122 In that case, the cause of your crashes is almost certainly that you're using pointers to objects that have ceased to exist a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have

```
void Job::generirateActivities(vector<Job> job_list) {
```

This means that when you call the function you make a copy of the vector and pass it to the function. You add values to it but you are actually adding to the copy, which is destroyed when you return.

You should modify it to

```
void Job::generirateActivities(vector<Job>& job_list) {
```

Note the `&` after vector.

Comment: That make my programm crash.
Maybe is problem in main than?
object.displayActivity(job_lists);

Comment: And also nothing is generated (I know that, because delete method says, that there is nothing to delete).